# Where are the Linux headers for Visual Studio *2019*

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I see this question has been asked before, and I have browsed through several answers, but most of them are nearly a decade old, and don't seem to be correct for more recent versions of VS.

I have installed Linux development with C++, but I can't seem to find any of the header files I need. I'm looking for things like `sys/ioctl.h`, `sys/uio.h`, etc.

Are they included in the Linux development environment? I'm looking to compile someone's CUDA program.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you need a Linux system to actually build despite the fact that VS 2019 supports the projects. You probably won't like the answer on where the headers are.

Comment: You compile and test your code on the remote Linux install, sounds like you skipped [this step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/configure-a-linux-project?view=msvc-160#remote-settings).  Or [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/configure-a-linux-project?view=msvc-160#remote_intellisense) if you get IntelliSense errors.